# Error 404 not found using contact-forms with a multilanguages site

Tags: wordpress, recaptcha, contact-form-7

With my web site, i use two languages, the default one is in english and the second is in french.
I have then two contact form for each languages and I used google reCAPTCHA within it.
For my english site, I can use the reCaptcha checkbox and submit my contact mail.
But for my french site, when I check the reCaptcha, I have an error:

**{"code":"rest_no_route","message":"No route was found matching the URL and request method","data":{"status":404}}**.

And I also have an error:

**my_address/wp-json/?lang=fr/contact-form-7/v1/contact-forms/{id}/feedback 404 (not found)**

Google reCaptcha intergration was made by contact-form-7 admin panel.

Does anyone have an idea to solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Might be the parameter `?lang=fr` that's being treated as part of the file path?  If that's the case, you'd need a function to strip it out.

Comment: You're right. After removing "?lang=fr" i can request to the server.